# How do I make a hasOne relationship reference an attribute on the model instead of the primary key?

Tags: model, laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

When defining a relationship, how do I tell the hasOne model to be joined using an attribute of the model other than the id?

My classes are:

```
Site
  id
  zipcode

LocationData
  id
  zipcode
```

When I run:

```
$site = Site::find(1);
$site->locationData
```

The query generated is:

```
select * from `location_data` where `location_data`.`zipcode` = 1 limit 1
```

Notice the zipcode column being referenced is passed 1 (the Site id), but I want it to use the Site's zipcode instead.

Note: I'm not asking how to set the foreign key on the child relationship, but how to pass that foreign key an attribute other than the parent's primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Here's a tweak:

Edit your model and move primaryKey to public visibility:

```
class Site extends Eloquent {

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    ....
}
```

Then you just have to set it whenever you need to:

```
$site = Site::find(1);
$site->primaryKey = 'zipcode';
$site->locationData;
```

Comment: This what I'm referring to in my "Note" section above. This tells the query to look at the zipcode as the foreign key on the child model, but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how do I pass the foreign key (zipcode) something other than the primary key of the parent model.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the relationship keys, while defining the relationships.

```
return $this->hasMany('Thing','key_to_use');
```